# How to choose correct version of gatsby-plugin-sharp when using FreeBSD v11.3 server?

Tags: gatsby, freebsd, sharp, pngquant

I'm trying to install and build Gatsby app on the FreeBSD v11.3 server. My gatsby app use gatsby-plugin-sharp and gatsby-transformer-sharp and I think those plugins cause the error.

This was the first error I got during npm install:

```
ERR! sharp BSD/SunOS systems require manual installation of libvips >= 8.9.1
```

So I installed older versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp and gatsby-transformer-sharp to match the installed libvips on the system (sharp v0.22.1). After that error disappeared but the next error appeared during gatsby build:

```
Error: pngquant: unrecognized option `--strip'
```

What should I do to make it work? What versions do I need to use?